# Lenovo Thinkpad E595 - Device Read Test failed?

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

Suddenly, my laptop didn't boot anymore. It was stuck on the following screen:

[image: boot screen]

Clicking any entry had no effect. I was stuck on this screen.

I run diagnostics test on it and I got the following result:

[image: test results]

The only failing test was the "Device Read Rest". What does it mean? Do I need to replace my SSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Lenovo Diagnostics myself. The Lenovo test was conclusive. Your drive has failed.

You need to see if you can boot from bootable USB Key (Windows ISO USB will work.

Then see if you can recover data.

If you cannot, you may need to ask a local recovery agency for help.

Comment: Thanks so far, that was helpful. Just to check If I got it right: The drive ist broken? It needs to be replaced?

Comment: Yes, the drive needs to be replaced; it cannot be fixed. You might get data from it (maybe not) - see a local recovery agency.